# 3 Table SQL JOIN not returning data

Tags: sql, join

The following query will not return any data. Cannot figure out why. Removing one of the joins works but then I can't get data from one table.

```
$productInfo = "SELECT stock.*, s_list.*, c_list.*
                FROM  stock
                INNER JOIN s_list
                ON stock.s_compo_id = s_list.id
                INNER JOIN c_list
                ON stock.c_compo_id = c_list.id
                WHERE batch_id = '$productID'";
```

Comment: If you are using prepared statement then done use single quotes around productId.

Comment: Because might be no matching data. Change `Inner Join` to `Left Join` and see for what condition are u getting `null`

Comment: Either your `join` conditions are wrong, or no records match the join conditions, or no products match the `batch_id`.  You need to provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Diffucult to guess without any data. The syntax seems to be OK, but maybe you don't always have the suitable records in *both* joined tables? What is the result like when you use `LEFT JOIN`s instead?

Comment: @cars10 when I left join I get the number of rows I want but no data from the s_list table

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT stock.*, s_list.*, c_list.*
FROM stock INNER JOIN
     s_list
     ON stock.s_compo_id = s_list.id INNER JOIN
     c_list
     ON stock.c_compo_id = c_list.id
WHERE batch_id = '$productID'";
```

Here are some reasons that I readily think of that you would get no data:

- `batch_id` and `$productID` don't match.  The names are different, so why should I think they refer to the same thing?
- Either `s_list` or `c_list` (or both) have no matching records.  You're doing inner joins, so no matching records would mean no rows are returned.
- You are getting rows, but the columns *have the same names* in the two tables.  For instance, you will likely see one `id` column in your output, and it is not clear which table it comes from.  **Explicitly list the columns you want and give them unique aliases.**

And, less likely because the naming looks right:

- The join conditions for one or both `join`s are not correct, so nothing matches.

And, an obligatory note that you should not be putting variables directly into query strings.  Use parameters.  Not only is it safer, but it gives the engine that opportunity to cache the query plan, saving effort when called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
    $productInfo = "SELECT stock.*, s_list.*, c_list.*
            FROM  stock
               LEFT JOIN s_list
                 ON stock.s_compo_id = s_list.id
               LEFT JOIN c_list
                  ON stock.c_compo_id = c_list.id
            WHERE batch_id = '$productID'";
```